# Bind Phantomjs to a Network Interface

Tags: phantomjs, iptables, ghostdriver, network-interface, remotewebdriver

I currently have multiple network alias (eth0, eht0:1, eth0:2), each having their own private ip which has its own public ip. When using remote web driver with phantomjs (ghostdriver), it always chooses the local host (See BUG https://github.com/ariya/phantomjs/issues/10269), for client argument --webdriver=ip:port, thus I cannot rely on phantomjs to pick the correct interface.

I am currently under the impression that I will have to use IPTABLES. I want to route ever instance of my java program using remote web driver to a different public ip when connecting to the phantomjs (ghostdriver) driver. Currently I can only control the port that it listens on.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is not so much binding an interface to phantomjs, but allowing phantomjs outbound traffic to use a specific network interface. I think I might need a reverse proxy.

Answer (score 2):

The best way so far to resolve this was to use a reverse proxy. Use the proxy option with phantomjs to specify the proxy ip and port, and configure a reverse proxy to redirect that traffic out.

Comment: Any code snippet would be super appreciated